# Alexa SDK Card - How to change the font size and font type of the text shown in the card

Tags: aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit

I would like to change the font-size and the font-type of the text in the Alexa card?

But I don't know if this is possible.

I would like your help,
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

**You cannot change font-size and font-type** of Alexa Card. 
However, you can include an image with a `Standard card`.

These are the different kinds of cards available.

1. **A Simple card** displays plain text. You provide text for the card title and content.
2. **A Standard card** also displays plain text, but can include an image. You provide the text for the title and content, and the URL for the image to display.
3. **A LinkAccount card** is a special card type only used with account linking. This card lets users start the account linking process.
4. **A Permissions Card** can be used to  ask customers for their consent to use resources such as address, postal code etc.

More on cards [here](https://developer.amazon.com/docs/custom-skills/include-a-card-in-your-skills-response.html)
Best practices for card design [here](https://developer.amazon.com/docs/custom-skills/best-practices-for-skill-card-design.html)

Comment: Is this still true? There is a skill called "Meine Wetterstation" for Netatmo and they display a fullscreen picture as a response, and the text is very small. How did they do that?

Comment: The statement above is still true but Amazon added a new presentation language called APL (Alexa Presentation Language) that gives you much greater control over the layout of your screen. The downside is APL is a very complicated JSON like language that is tricky to work with.